# Javascript UTC Date Conversion

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a function that I pass a date string to and I need to determine if that supplied date is in the past based on the current UTC Date.

I think my issue is coming from the `dateToUTC` function as it is returning the date at 7am UTC where the `currentUTC` gives me the full timestamp.

It's almost as if I need to append the `hh/mm/ss` to the end of the date I provide in order to check?

Any thoughts on how I can tweak this?

```
// I expect this to return false since the UTC DATE is not 08/17/2017
alert(isHistoricalChange('08/16/2017'))

/**
 * Determine if the start date supplied is in the past
 */
function isHistoricalChange(startDate){
    // dateToUTC(startDate) = 1502866800000
    // currentUTC() = 1502903243386
    return (dateToUTC(startDate) < currentUTC());
}


/**
 * Returns the current timestamp in UTC
 */
function currentUTC() {
  return Date.now();
}


/**
 * Returns timestamp in UTC based on date supplied
 */
function dateToUTC(d) {
  return new Date(d).getTime();
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/981ats14/

Comment: You should consider using something like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to deal with times so you don't have to.

Comment: @SumnerEvans - Do you have an example of how I could accomplish this with that library?

Comment: You can get the difference easily from two `moment` objects http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/. I recommend just looking at the docs and seeing what it has to offer and see if it lines up with what you want to accomplish. I personally have not used it before, but I've heard it's a good library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you want "08/16/2017" (which I assume is 16 August, 2017) to be parsed as UTC and then to see if it is prior to the current date, then you can use a simple parse function.

The current "UTC date" is provided by `new Date()`, since Date objects are UTC. The host timezone setting used to calculate the current UTC time, and usually by the *toString* and *toLocaleString* methods to return a date and time in the host timezone. But the underlying value in the Date object is UTC.

So you can parse "08/16/2017" as UTC and simply compare it to *new Date()*:

```js
function parseMDYasUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1]));
}

var d = parseMDYasUTC('08/16/2017')
console.log('2017-08-16 parsed as UTC:\n' + d.toString() + 
            ' or \n' + d.toISOString());

console.log('Is "08/16/2017" UTC before today? ' +
            (parseMDYasUTC("08/16/2017") < new Date()));
```

The string "2017-08-16" should be parsed by the built-in parser as UTC, however string parsing is notoriously unreliable so always manually parse strings. A library can help but a simple function is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly creating a Date object. You should call your function like this: `alert(isHistoricalChange('2017-8-17'))`.

Below are examples of the date constructor:

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
```

To read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question.

Comment: His logic works fine but, in my opinion, OP is trying to input an improperly formatted date. If he passes `2017-08-17` to his function instead of `08/16/2017`, then his snippet works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As you've guessed, currentUTC is returning the current datetime, not just the date. You can modify it like so to get the beginning of the day:

```
function currentUTC() {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    return d.getTime()
}
```